# Light gray asset on black background - Blurry

Tags: image, css, svg, background

I have a light gray SVG button in a label with black background. The SVG button seems 'blurry' / 'bolder' on the edges. This is not something I can notice when using a white background.

I suppose it is related to the high contrast between background and asset colour.

How can I get this better?

[image]

Btw, I'm using the SVG has background image of a div and respecting the original size of image.

CSS code of the div containing the SVG asset:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
width: 42px;
height: 42px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
top: 20px;
right: 20px;
background-image: url(/assets/images/icons/create-document-close-button.svg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: transparent;
background-size: 36px 36px;
background-position: center center;
transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
```

The SVG code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="36px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 36 36" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs></defs>
<g id="States" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Buttons-&amp;-States-(Documents-Steps)" transform="translate(-104.000000, -138.000000)">
        <g id="Close-Button" transform="translate(104.000000, 138.000000)">
            <g>
                <circle id="circle" fill="#E9EEF2" cx="18" cy="18" r="18"></circle>
                <polygon id="X" fill="#9FADB5" transform="translate(17.868000, 17.808000) rotate(-45.000000) translate(-17.868000, -17.808000) " points="16.968 23.616 18.768 23.616 18.768 18.672 23.736 18.672 23.736 16.944 18.768 16.944 18.768 12 16.968 12 16.968 16.944 12 16.944 12 18.672 16.968 18.672"></polygon>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D I understand that, but this seems more a theorectical answer than a practical one.

Comment: Just provided the CSS code. Thanks!

Comment: Just provided it @Paulie_D. Thanks!

Comment: Not related but I'd suggest you remove the height and width from the SVG. That fixes the size which you really don't need.

Comment: Ok, for my next SVG's, I'll will ask that to my designer. Thanks for the advice.